# GAE(Google App Engine) Java8 令和 対応していますか？

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java8

サンプルプログラムをデプロイしてみて実行したところ、（西暦年は 2022年です）
ローカル環境では「令和4」が表示されますが、デプロイしたGAEの環境では「平成34」になります。

GAE環境で「令和」対応する方法はないでしょうか？

```
public String strNowJpYmd(String jpYmdFormat) {
  try {
    Date date = new Date();

    Locale locale = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
    SimpleDateFormat jpfrm = new SimpleDateFormat(jpYmdFormat, locale);
    jpfrm.setTimeZone(tz);
    return jpfrm.format(date);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return "ERROR";
  }
}

logger.log(Level.WARNING, "strYmdToJpYmd()" + strNowJpYmd("GGGGGy-MM-dd")));
```